# Google Custom Search Engine Java output

Tags: java, arrays, google-custom-search

I am running this program just fine :

```
package cse;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class cse {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String key = "My API KEY";
    String qry = "Test";
    if(qry.contains(" ")) {
        qry = qry.replace(' ', '+');
        System.out.println("here");
        System.out.println(qry);
    }
    URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="+key+ "&cx=MY_CUSTOM SEARCH&q="+qry+"&alt=json");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");

    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(output.contains("\"link\": \"")) {                
            String link = output.substring(output.indexOf("\"link\": \"")+("\"link\": \"").length(), output.indexOf("\","));
            System.out.println(link);       //Will print the google search links
        }     
    }
    conn.disconnect();                              
}

}
```

Now what I want to do is have it only return the one result, and add this result to a string array. I could even just grab the first result and put it in there if that would be easier but I'm just not sure how to go about this.

So basically, if I searched the same query three times, the array would consist of   `[http://www.speedtest.net/,http://www.speedtest.net/,http://www.speedtest.net/]`

Thanks in advance for any help, which would be much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I am unsure how to parse the output so that I only receive one result then pass said result into an array. So the first result for test is www.speedtest.net I want to store this value anf ignore the rest of the output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the data (ascending or descending) use a Query. The Table doesn't have any order. Even the Fields don't have any relevant order.